# Why are these two codes giving different output? isn't a for loop just a short-hand for a while loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

-I'm trying to make a program that checks if a number is a strong number or not.

-I'm using C language.

-My problem is that i can't seem to find the difference between a for and a while loop, even when they look identical they always give different outputs for some reason.

-even though this is *not* the first time i encounter such a problem, but i never seem to find the difference!

-Here's the code with the for loop: (gives the output that i expected)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number, q, rem, fac = 1, result=0, i;
    printf("please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    q = number;
    i = 1;

    while(q != 0){
        rem = q%10;
        for(i = 1; i<=rem; i++){      //   <---  THE FOR LOOP HERE  ****
            fac = fac*i;
        }
        result = result + fac;
        fac = 1;
        q = q/10;
    }

    if(number == result){
        printf("%d is a strong number", number);
    }
    else{
        printf("-%d is not a strong number\n", number);
        printf("-your result was %d instead of %d", result, number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

-Here's the **same** code with the while loop: (gives the wrong output)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number, q, rem, fac = 1, result=0, i;
    printf("please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    q = number;
    i = 1;

    while(q != 0){
        rem = q%10;
        while(i <= rem){      //   <---  THE WHILE LOOP HERE  ****               
            fac = fac*i;
            i++;
        }
        result = result + fac;
        fac = 1;
        q = q/10;
    }

    if(number == result){
        printf("%d is a strong number", number);
    }
    else{
        printf("-%d is not a strong number\n", number);
        printf("-your result was %d instead of %d", result, number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` is not reset back to `1` in the second example at the start of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: Suggest you learn/do basic debugging. Run the program in a debugger or even just use basic debug print statements. Problem should then have been obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle but important difference between the posted versions:

- in `for(i = 1; i<=rem; i++)` the iteration variable `i` is initialized to `1` at each occurrence of the loop.
- in the second version, `while(i <= rem)` uses the same test and `i++` in the loop body performs the same incrementation, but the initialization `i = 1;`  occurs only once before the outer loop, hence the different behavior.

This question is a perfect example of the superiority of the `for` loop over the `while` loop for simple iterations. It is counterproductive to mandate the use of `while` loops in coding conventions, such as those enforced in some French CS schools.